# Incorrect use of functions/Global Variables?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a technique question...I got the desired result by using this code but for some reason, it doesn't seems like it's the "proper" way to program. Can anyone tell me if my code is entirely reasonable or if there is a better way to do this?

So I needed to access the changed value of the slider and save it to my backend (Parse) but because I added the slider/table cells programmatically, I had a hard time accessing the changed value directly.

So I created a global variable named theDistance and set it equal to the slider's changed value text and then put it in a function to save it.

Is this the correct approach for such a task?

```
  var theDistance: String = ""

 @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        runSearch()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toBrowsePage", sender: self)

}

func runSearch() {

    var mySearch = PFObject(className: "Searches")
    mySearch["distanceSearches"] = String(theDistance)
    mySearch.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if success {

        }
    })
}




func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    var slider = sender
    let cell = self.theTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: slider.tag, inSection: 0)) as UITableViewCell!

    for view in cell.subviews {
        var theValue = Int(slider.value)
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.text = "\(theValue)" + "mi."
            theDistance = label.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach would be to directly update your data model with the new data as soon as it changes, and then always pull data from the model layer. Caching the changed result is not the optimal way to handle this.

You're intuition about that code is right; it will cause miscellaneous bugs when you update your layouts or functionality in the future.

Comment: In addition to John's point, you should use an instance variable or property instead of a global. Avoid globals when there is an alternative. They cause tight coupling of your different modules.